# unable to receive and process snmp packets having RequestID 0

Tags: snmp4j

I have a snmp enabled device whose monitoring i want to do.
But this device gives response with Request-ID 0 for all the get request. snmp4j library
discards these received packets because it sends get request  with some Request-ID value other than 0. On receiving the response it matches the sent "Request-ID" value with the received "Request-ID" value and on finding mismatch it just discards the received packet and returns "null" value to response.

If I set the Request-ID to 0 in snmp packet before sending get request then response snmp packet can be processed.

For this snmp4j library contains the "setRequestID(Integer32 (value))" function to set the desired Request-ID of any snmp packet, but this function cannot set the Request-ID value to 0. When I set the value to 0, this  function replaces this value to some random Request-ID value.

If any one having solution then please give response.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The request-id field is used to identify the response when it arrives back to the client.  So, if the device you are querying at is returning all requests with a request-id value of 0 instead of the supplied value, then the client (snmp4j) is correctly discarding the response because it is invalid.  The request-id in the response packet must always match the request-id in the original request.  The device has a buggy SNMP stack.  If you change your code to force the requests to always have a request-id of 0 you are breaking functionality to enable compatibility with a non-standard agent and I would advise against it.